# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException through reference chain when there is inconsistency between member type and accessor methods

Tags: java, junit, jackson

Is there a configuration to allow Jackson gracefully handle members discrepancy between member variable's type and that used in the getter/setter?  For example, if a private variable is declared with type ***Long*** and its accessor methods are using type ***long***, we have a problem.  Also, we are dealing with code which cannot be changed:

For example, consider this class:

```
    public class EventArgs {

        private Long id;
        private String message;


        public String getMessage() {
            return message;
        }

        public void setMessage(String message) {
            this.message = message;
        }

        public long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

}
```

Consider the corresponding test:

```
@Test
    public void shouldSerializeToString() {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String value = null;
        try {
            value = mapper.writeValueAsString(new EventArgs());
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Assert.assertNotNull(value);
    }
```

The test fails with this exception:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: (was
>   java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain:
>   com.sailpoint.orchestration.zeebe.model.EventArgs["id"])  at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:394)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:353)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer.wrapAndThrow(StdSerializer.java:316)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:729)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:166)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._configAndWriteValue(ObjectMapper.java:4094)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(ObjectMapper.java:3404)
>     at
>   com.sailpoint.orchestration.zeebe.workers.EventArgsTests.shouldSerializeToString(EventArgsTests.java:19)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)    at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)     at
>   org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)    at
>   com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   com.sailpoint.orchestration.zeebe.model.EventArgs.getId(EventArgs.java:18)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:688)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:721)
>     ... 28 more
>
> java.lang.AssertionError  at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:86)    at
>   org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:41)   at
>   org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull(Assert.java:712)   at
>   org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull(Assert.java:722)   at
>   com.sailpoint.orchestration.zeebe.workers.EventArgsTests.shouldSerializeToString(EventArgsTests.java:24)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)    at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)     at
>   org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)    at
>   com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)

Answer (score 2):

You could tell Jackson not to use `getters` and `setters` and use fields only :

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE); //turn off everything
mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY); // only use fields
```

or if you want to disable ONLY getters and setters and use fields (and allow other like JsonCreator) :

```
mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.SETTER, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE);
mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.GETTER, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE);
mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
```

The output JSON is then :

```
{"id":null,"message":null}
```